# How do I center and make the contents of this page bigger?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my website: http://foxweb.marist.edu/users/kf79g/contact.php

Testing website: http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoxweb.marist.edu%2Fusers%2Fkf79g%2Fcontact.php

On my contact page, I want the form along with the text and icons to be as big as possible across all screen sizes as well as centered on the page. In particular, on medium size screens like tablets (refer to the testing website link) you can see that there is a ton of white space on the page, and the content itself is very small to look at. This is why I want to make the page easier to look at by making everything bigger.

All of my code is located in the page source under these files (after right clicking view source on your browser):

screen_styles.css

screen_layout_large.css

screen_layout_small.css

screen_layout_medium.css

contact.php

I tried about everything in my knowledge to fix it, but I have been proven unsuccessful. I tried centering the whole thing as best as I can, but it is not completely even on medium and small screens (refer to how the form and icons are set up to see that the measurements are off). On small screens, it is ruining my responsive design by going out of the page a little. After this is done, my website will finally be finished. Please help me out I need to get this done as soon as possible. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media query (you decide the breakpoint value) and put the new styling for `#contact_section` like the example below

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    #contact_section {
        float:none;
        display: block;
        width: 96%;
        padding: 2%;
        box-shadow: none; /*if don't want any shadow*/
    }
}
```

*p/s: 640px is the example of the breakpoint value*

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However, I tried this but I was not able to adjust it properly to what I wanted. Do you have any other suggestions?